# VHDL error signals

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl

i m trying to do an digital clock, but only in simulator, i dont need to test it on FPGA board. I dont need to use clock for changing the seconds.

```
begin  
an <= random_gen(2000, 2017); 
luna<= random_gen(1,12);
temp<=random_gen(-15, 35);

process(ora)
begin
    if mounth = 9 or mounth = 4 or mounth =6 or mounth = 11 then
        day<=random_gen(1,30);
    elsif mounth = 1 or mounth = 3 or mounth = 5 or mounth = 7 or mounth = 8 or mounth = 9 or mounth = 10 or mounth = 12 then
        day<=random_gen(1,31);
    elsif mounth = 2 and (an = 2000 or an = 2004 or an = 2008 or an = 2012 or an = 20016) then
        day<=random_gen(1,28);
    else day<=random_gen(1,29);
    end if;    
end process;

hour<=random_gen(1,23);
min<=random_gen(1,59);
sec<=random_gen(1,59);

process(sec)
begin
    sec<=sec+1;
        if(sec = 59) then
            sec<=0;
            min <= min + 1;
            if(min = 59) then
                hour <= hour + 1;
                min <= 0;
                if(hour = 23) then
                    hour <= 0;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
end process;
end architecture;
```

The error that i get is : Signal "sec" has two sources, but is not resolved signal.

Also i get it for "min" and "hour"

Comment: You are assigning `sec<=random_gen(1,59);` as a concurrent assignment, as well as `sec<=sec+1;` in your process. What do you expect this to do? I suspect you just want to delete the `random_gen` lines.

Comment: Also, you do need to use a clock to change the seconds. You could use a clock signal or a wait statement, but without either of these, your code does not make sense.

Comment: We're missing the signal declarations in the code... please write a MCVE...

Comment: it's ok, i fix it. Ty guys.